# Vector vs. Matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

What is the difference between these notations:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

And:
\begin{equation*}
x 
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
0  \\
\end{pmatrix}
+ 
y
\begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

And:

\begin{equation*}
\langle1,0 \rangle x  + \langle0,1 \rangle y
\end{equation*}

Are they all the same? Why is vector notation sometimes used and matrix notation sometimes used?

Comment: They are the same. A linear transformation defined by a matrix is equivalent to the span of the column vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter two notations are the same if one takes
$\langle a,b \rangle :=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
 b
\end{pmatrix}$. This notation is sometimes used to have vectors written in-line. In this case, what you have is a linear combination of the two standard vectors:

$$x\langle 1,0 \rangle+y\langle 0,1 \rangle
=x\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
 0
\end{pmatrix} + y\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
 1
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} = \langle x,y \rangle$$
Notice that these are both notations for vectors. The first notation is for a 2-by-2 matrix, which is **not** a vector unlike the latter two expressions. You can write the latter two expressions using the matrix-vector product, which might be the source of your confusion. In the 2-by-2 case the matrix-vector product is defined
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
c & d
\end{bmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix} =x\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}
b\\ 
d
\end{pmatrix}$$
From this it should be trivial to see what 2-by-2 matrix is used to give you your latter two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually all the same! It is only a way of representation! If you take the first one, you'll have a matrix with just numbers that represent linear combinations!

The second one actually shows linear combinations in the form: cw + dv; where w and v are the vectors! And C and D are the scalars, which in your case is x and y.

And the angled bracket you see "<>" represents an inner product, for example, the scalar product or the dot product